# Find a column with specific header, then translate it into coordinates, make it a variable and include it into a function

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to run on reports that change very often (basically every time we pull them, the columns can be in a different order). However the headers are always the same so I have made a code that "detects" the headers and allows my formulas to be applied on the right columns.

I have another problem now: I need this same concept (finding a column from its header rather than its coordinates) but applied to an IF formula:

Somewhere in my spreadsheet will be a column "Degree" and somewhere else a column "Graduation Date".
I want the macro to find the column Graduation Date and add a new column next to it, and call it "B.S Graduation Date" (this part, I got. It works).

Now, in "B.S Graduation Date" I would like a formula saying:
*"If (Column "Degree", Row 1) says "Associate Degree", then put [(column "Graduation Date", Row 1)]+2 years"*

It is a simple IF formula but I need it to include the feature allowing it to find those columns from their headers and not specific coordinates.

I was thinking there might be a way to find the header, translate it into coordinates, then translate the coordinates into a variable, and include that variable into the formula.

I guess something like:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet    
Dim rngLocation As Range    
Dim rngNewCol As Range    
Dim lRow As Long    
Set ws = ActiveSheet    
Set rngLocation = ws.Rows(1).Find("Degree")    
'Give me the coordinates for that header  
'Those coordinates = (x,y)
```

And then select the column, fill it with the IF formula with the variable (x,y) in there.
The only things I need a code for are the two lines preceded by an apostrophe. Also, I would need several variables for each IF function (2 sets. One from which the test will be, and the other for the column from which the values are extracted: IF ((x,y) = 1, (Offset 0,0) = (w,z) + 2).

Please let me know if you can think of a way to do that or if you need more information.

EDIT: following stucharo's indications, here is the code I have been using:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet  
Set rngLocation = ws.Rows(1).Find("Graduation Date")  
If rngLocation Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  
rngLocation.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert  
Set rngNewCol = rngLocation.Offset(, 1)  
lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row - 1  
rngNewCol.Value = "B.S. Graduation Date"  
With rngNewCol.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow)  
.NumberFormat = "General"  
'the above creates a new column and make it in format general
'next comes stucharo's code (that I tried to adapt)
Dim degreeCol As Integer  
degreeCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("Degree").Column  
Dim gradDateCol As Integer  
gradDateCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("Graduation Date (MM/DD/YYYY)").Column  
Dim bsGradDateCol As Integer  
bsGradDateCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("B.S. Graduation Date").Column  
Dim row As Integer  
For row = 2 To endRow  
If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Bachelor's degree (±16 years)" Then  
ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value  
End If  
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Doctorate degree over (±19 years)" Then
ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", -3, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Master's degree (±18 years)" Then
ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", -2, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Associate's degree college diploma (±13 years)" Then
ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 3, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Technical diploma (±12 years)" Then
ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 4, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = " " Then
ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = "No Data"
End If
Next row
```

This does not create any error but it does not populate the cells either. Please if you see what I am doing wrong let me know.
Thanks!!

Comment: it's difficult to tell without seeing your worksheet.  Can you check that the `degreeCol`, `gradDateCol` and `bsGradDateCol` variables hold the correct column numbers?

Comment: And where is `endrow` defined?  You'll end up with a variable of type `Empty`, i think, if it's not defined before you use it so the loop will never execute as it doesn't have an end point.

Comment: that's the only problem I can see with your code, the rest works perfectly, i've updated my solution to find the `endRow` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `Cells()` property?  It lets you reference a cell by a row number and column number e.g. `Cells(1,1)` (row 1, column1) is the same as `Range("A1")`.  This is useful if you create an integer to store the `Degree` column number:

```
Dim degreeCol As Integer
degreeCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("Degree").Column
```

You can do the same thing to reference the "Graduation Date" and "B.S. Graduation Date":

```
Dim gradDateCol As Integer
gradDateCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("Graduation Date").Column
Dim bsGradDateCol As Integer
bsGradDateCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("B.S. Graduation Date").Column
```

Now, assuming these titles are on row 1 of your worksheet and the data starts on row 2 you can reference the cell using the `Cells()` property:

```
If ws.Cells(2, degreeCol).Value = "Associate Degree" Then
    ws.Cells(2, bsGradDateCol).Value = ws.Cells(2, gradDateCol).Value + 2
End If
```

On top of that, if you have a table you can place all that inside a `For Loop` to increment the row number and work down the entire table.  Furthermore, if you have multiple operations on each row you can place them all inside the `For Loop`, find the number of the last row and step through them row wise:

```
Dim endRow As Integer
endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Dim row As Integer
For row = 2 To endRow
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Associate Degree" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 2, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
    End If

    'Add further IF statements inside this loop to carry out 
    'additional operations on a row wise basis.
    'You may need to create more column references using the
    '.Find().Column() method used above.

Next row
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot stucharo, it seems like it can solve my problem! I do have a couple questions though: 1) how do you "nest" several IF functions this way? I would have 6 of them. Do I put the whole block of code everytime?    2) I simplified it in my original question: the data in column "Graduation Date" is...dates. I cannot just ask "add 2". I need to add 2 years. Do you have any idea how to implement that in the code? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Sorenn022 Both of those are achievable, i've modified my answer to include them.  You don't really need to nest the If functions (nesting would be placing an IF inside another IF) you just need to execute them all sequentially using the same row number in each check.  If you place all your IF statements inside the `For Loop` the will execute one after the other using the same value of row until the proocedure loops and `row` is incremented.

Comment: @Sorenn022 Apologies, I forgot to increment the date correctly, I was too busy with the actual algorithm, I've included it now using the `DateAdd` function.  It could probably be the topic of a whole other question so I didn't dwell on it too much, but you should read the documentation, particularly regarding how to define intervals.  This approach depends on the cell on the worksheet being formatted as a date.  If so, VBA will create a `Date` object rather than a `String` or `Variant`.  If not, you might have to create a new date object and split up the string into portions.

Comment: Sorry, I must be doing something wrong, the code does not create any error but does not add anything in the column either. I will edit my question with the code I use for you to see. Hopefully you can spot what I am doing wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: @Sorenn022 I've updated the answer to define the `endRow` variable, which I'd missed out.  For info, it's useful to add `Option Explicit` (Tools -> Options. -> Require Variable Declaration) to the top of each module to prevent undeclared variables being allowed.  This means you have to explicitly declare each variable (`Dim endRow as Integer`) before you can use it and prevents hard to find bugs (like `endRow` being of type `Empty`) finding there way into your code.

Comment: It works with the end row variable. Thank you so much stucharo! I really appreciate your help!